# Angular disable dropdown menu in Reactive Form until value in another dropdown menu has been set

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-reactive-forms, disable

I want a dropdown menu "subcategories" to be disabled with a grey background (and no possibility to open the dropdown menu with the defined placeholder) until the user has selected a value from the dropdownmenu "categories". I'm working with reactive forms. My lists "categories" and "subcategories" are hardcoded in the component class and I have a list selectedSubcategories declared on top to retain the list of subcategories based on the chosen category.

In the template-driven approach, I managed to disable this dropdown by using the [disabled] attribute.

My html for the dropdown menu "categories":

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="selectChangeCategory($event)">
          <option disabled selected>Select...</option>
          <option *ngFor="let category of categories">
            {{category.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

The selectChangeCategory method who keeps track of the value chosen in the dropdown menu "categories":

```
selectChangeCategory(event: any){
    this.selectedCategory = event.target.value;
    this.selectedSubcategories = this.selectSubcategory(this.selectedCategory);
  }
```

The selectSubcategory method who returns the right list of subcategories:

```
selectSubcategory(selectedCategory: string){
  if(selectedCategory == "Category 1"){
    this.selectedSubcategories = this.subcategoriesCategory1;
  }
  else if(selectedCategory == "Category 2"){
    this.selectedSubcategories = this.subcategoriesCategory2;
  }
  else{
    this.selectedSubcategories = [{name: 'empty!'}];
  }
  return this.selectedSubcategories;
  }
```

My html for the dropdown menu "subcategories":

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="selectSubcategory(selectedCategory)" value="subcategory.name" [disabled]="selectedCategory===''">
          <option disabled selected >Select...</option>
          <option *ngFor="let subcategory of selectedSubcategories">
            {{subcategory.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

The `[disabled]="selectedCategory===''"` works perfectly in the template-driven approach. The dropdown menu "subcategories" has a nice grey background and is disabled until the user selects a category. In the reactive form approach, this code fails. I manage to display only subcategories when a category has been chosen, but you can still open the dropdown menu of "subcategories" and see the "Select..." label.

Edit: this is my code in the ngOnchanges() method:

```
ngOnChanges(){
    this.selectedSubcategories = this.selectSubcategory(this.selectedCategory);
  }
```

I really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in reactive form you should disable controls in one of these forms

```
FormControl({value: '', disabled: true})
```

or reactivly

```
control.disable() 
control.enable()
```

because in template driven form you actually set [disable attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) on control.
or if you want a simpler solution you can create a custom directive like this

```
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[disableControl]'
})
export class DisableControlDirective {

  @Input() set disableControl( condition : boolean ) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }

  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl ) {
  }

}
```

This directive does exactly `disable` attribute in context of reactive form

Comment: I want to try your first approach. Can you explain where I can put the `control.disable()` (so without the separate directive)? How can I add the condition that the control can be enabled only when a category has been chosen?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with reactive form implementation. Check below example, this should resolve your issue. You can use **[disabled]="!categoryForm.controls['category'].value"** condition directly on **formControlName** so that if something is selected subcategories will be enabled then only. Also try to avoid assignment in **ngOnChanges** as it will get called a lot of times. Try assigning  after initialization of service  or after **ngAfterViewInit** hook.

```
      constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder){} //take an instance of FormBuilder
                
                this.categoryForm= this.formBuilder.group({
                  'category': [''], //if you want to initialize any selected value you can pass it directly here
                  'subCategory': ['']
            }); // initialize a form group
                 
             selectChangeCategory(event: any){
              this.selectedCategory = this.categoryForm.controls['category'].value;
              this.selectedSubcategories = this.selectSubcategory(this.selectedCategory);
             }
            selectSubcategory(selectedCategory: string){
              if(selectedCategory == "Category 1"){
              this.selectedSubcategories = this.subcategoriesCategory1;
            }
           else if(selectedCategory == "Category 2"){
            this.selectedSubcategories = this.subcategoriesCategory2;
           }
           else{
            this.selectedSubcategories = [{name: 'empty!'}];
           }
          return this.selectedSubcategories;
         }
//html file
    <form  [formGroup]="categoryForm" >
               <select class="form-control" formControlName="category" (change)="selectChangeCategory($event)">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [value]="cat.name">
                        {{cat.name}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="subCategory"(change)="selectSubcategory(selectedCategory)[disabled]="!categoryForm.controls['category'].value">
                      <option value="" disabled selected >Select...</option>
                      <option *ngFor="let scat of selectedSubcategories" [value]="scat.name">
                        {{scat.name}}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                </form>
```

Let me know if you still face any challenge. Thank You.

**Other ways :**  Instead of adding disabled condition in html
this.categoryForm= this.formBuilder.group({
'category': [''], //if you want to initialize any selected value you can pass it directly here
'subCategory': [{value: '', disabled: !this.selectedCategory}]
}); // initialize a form group

Comment: I tried your code and now my dropdown for category is empty. I removed the html and the dropdown for category is filled again. The dropdown for subcategory isn't disabled. I can open it and see the Select... option, but there are no values in it.

Comment: please check the updated answer..maybe formControlName and *ngFor let var name was same that is why the dropdown was not loading , also in disable condition   formGroup is  categoryForm. Try again with this.

Comment: I think changing the names in the ngFor to avoid confusion with the formControlName is a good suggestion. The values appear again. I like your creative way of thinking about a solution for disabling the dropdown. Unfortunately, it's still not working... The dropdown is disabled, but stays disabled even when I select a category.

Comment: did u add the disable condition to  formGroup or html ?

Comment: I've added the disable condition to the FormControl and added `this.form.controls['subcategory'].enable()` to the selectChangeCategory method. That works! Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.form.controls['formControlName'].enable()
```

or

```
this.form.controls['formControlName'].disable()
```

works